# How to calculate decile ranks for multiple columns in dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1465 observations and 1074 variables. Each Column is a date and each row is a different stock ticker. I need to rank the tickers for each date.

So far I have been stuck at even ranking only a single column in the dataset. After searching the internet most sources seem to suggest the use of `cut(X, quantile(X,(0:10)/10, include.lowest=TRUE`. I have tried:

```
DecRanking <- Volume 
DecRanking <- as.data.frame(DecRanking)
DecRanking2 <- NULL

DecRanking2 <- cut(DecRanking[,1], quantile(DecRanking[,1],(0:10)/10),include.lowest=TRUE)
DecRanking2 <- cut(DecRanking$X1.6.1995, quantile(DecRanking$X1.6.1995,(0:10)/10),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

This give the error: `'breaks' are not unique`. When enclosing the quintile function in `unique()` it presents an output that is completely wrong:

```
> head(DecRanking2)
[1] (1e+03,1.93e+04] [0,1e+03]        [0,1e+03]        (1e+03,1.93e+04]      [0,1e+03]        (1e+03,1.93e+04]
Levels: [0,1e+03] (1e+03,1.93e+04] (1.93e+04,4.33e+07]
```

How do I fix this and how will achieve the calculation of all columns?

EDIT:

```
 > head(DecRanking)
  X1.6.1995 X1.13.1995 X1.20.1995 X1.27.1995 X2.3.1995 X2.10.1995 X2.17.1995 X2.24.1995 X3.3.1995 X3.10.1995 X3.17.1995
1      4300          0          0       3300      9900        200        200        400      3100          0        700
2         0          0          0          0         0          0          0          0         0          0          0
3         0          0          0          0         0          0          0          0         0          0          0
4     13700       4700      39400       2400     37645      51486      10000      41650       400      12007      22500
5         0          0          0          0         0          0          0          0         0          0          0
6     10300       6500          0       2500      4800       2500          0      15700        20          0          0
```

That is just an extract of the data. in fear of stating the obvious - the data obviously has 1,465 rows and 1074 columns

Comment: Can you provide us the output of `head(DecRanking)`?

Comment: I edited my question to include the `head(DecRanking)` data.

Comment: if your data is sparse (as per the head sample), you may not event have all 10 deciles populated. That's the reason for the error `'breaks' are not unique`: you have several deciles which have the same value of 0, and you can't have duplicate values for the breaks in `cut`.

So you have mentioned the wrong output. Maybe you can give example of one right output, so we can figure out how you want to handle e.g. where the value is 0 and deciles 0%, 10%, ... 40% are all 0, how should your output look like?

Comment: Check dplyr package on how to find the ranks of the elements of your numeric column. There's a "rank" command.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, not sure how you want to treat cases where there are not enough data to create distinct decile ranks.

If you're happy to simply divide the range into 10 bins of equal size between 0 to the highest value in a particular date, you can do the following (bin 1 being 0, bin 10 being the one with the highest value):

```
DecRanking2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(DecRanking, function(x)
    cut(x, 10, labels=paste("Bin", 1:10), include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

Using `DecRanking` containing only your sample 6-line data, this is the output

```
> DecRanking2
  X1.6.1995 X1.13.1995 X1.20.1995 X1.27.1995 X2.3.1995 X2.10.1995 X2.17.1995 X2.24.1995 X3.3.1995 X3.10.1995 X3.17.1995
1     Bin 4      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 10     Bin 3      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1    Bin 10      Bin 1      Bin 1
2     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1
3     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1
4    Bin 10      Bin 8     Bin 10      Bin 8    Bin 10     Bin 10     Bin 10     Bin 10     Bin 2     Bin 10     Bin 10
5     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1
6     Bin 8     Bin 10      Bin 1      Bin 8     Bin 2      Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 4     Bin 1      Bin 1      Bin 1
```

Comment: I will play around with your suggestion a bit. I think a large part of my problem is a lack of knowledge in both using R and how decile ranking works. Also I honestly don't know what is the proper methodology for cases where there is not enough data to create distinct decile ranks.

Comment: Somewhere on the internet someone proposed the following:    "The problem is that quantile() produces multiple values 
for the breaks used in cut(). It might be preferable to modify the breaks: 

   `eps <- .Machine$double.eps  #or use something like 1e-10     
   brks <- quantile(vec, (0:10)/10) + eps*(0:10)   
   cut(vec, brks, include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE)`   

Would this be a correct solution?

Comment: Also, your solution would be perfect if it was equally distributed (even roughly would suffice). Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Please define "equally distributed" because I believe mine is, but our definition may differ.

As I said in comment, the best way is for you to give an example of a correct solution (maybe worked out by hand) so we know what you have in mind. Not just showing the wrong solution as what you have in your question currently

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I understand now what you want from me and it is obvious that I started this project without clearly defining in what for I need my results for statistical evaluation. I will clarify this for myself and then post back here.